# Make bulges in geometry in a specific place

Tags: geometry, subdivision-surface

I have this mesh on a screenshot that I made. Bulges, I'm talking about nails, were made using boolean, remesh and subdivision modifiers, but can it be different? Can I somehow make a clean geometry with these bulges? Second screenshot has a geometry without them.

[image: Circle]

[image: Circle without bulges]

Comment: are you talking about the nails all around or the circular bumps?

Comment: About nails, they were made using boolean modifier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a circle with as many vertices as necessary, 48 for you if you have 14 nails, only keep one slice:

[image]

Extrude up, remove the faces on the sides:

[image]

Remove a central vertex, select the edge around, extrude inwards, then right click > *LoopTools > Circle* to get the circle, extrude up:

[image]

Create the bumps:

[image]

Use the *Array* modifier with an empty as *Object Offset*, rotate the empty to make the whole shield:

[image]